# Зарисовать область пересечения двух треуглольников

Tags: python, алгоритм, вычислительная-геометрия

Собственно, вся задача. Треугольники заданы координатами своих вершин.

Как это математически рассчитать я не догадался, но придумал, как "обхитрить" - залить треугольники разными цветами и там, где они пересекаются, будет третий цвет.

Вопрос - как это сделать? Из  графики в Python знаком только с turtle, а там, насколько я знаю, один цвет накладывается на другой и делать их прозрачными нельзя.

Comment: А математическое решение задачи вас не интересует?)

Answer (score 1):

Математическое решение задачи возможно двумя путями.

Первый, шаткий, но быстрый - искать пересечения сторон и положения сторон относительно друг друга. Это банальная аналитическая геометрия за первый курс. Проблема тут в том, что на уродливых треугольниках формулки начнут давать страшные погрешности и ломаться.

Второй, по сути, это тот, по которому вы пошли. Растеризуем треугольники. Искать пересечение растров - дело тривиальное. Большинство "крутых" геометрических библиотек именно растеризуют.

Answer (score 1):

Давайте всё же попробуем решить алгоритмическую проблему.

Задачу «найти пересечение двух треугольников» можно обобщить до её индуктивного замыкания: «найти пересечение двух выпуклых многоугольников». Их пересечением, понятно, будет новый выпуклый многоугольник.

Поскольку выпуклый многоугольник есть пересечение полуплоскостей, содержащих его стороны (очевидно), то задача сводится к индуктивному применению нахождения пересечения выпуклого многоугольника с полуплоскостью. (Полуплоскости у нас будут считаться *включающими* границу.)

Как решать такую задачу? Для начала подумаем, как полуплоскость может пересекаться с выпуклым многоугольником.

1. Все вершины многоугольника лежат вне полуплоскости. Пересечение пусто.
2. Все вершины многоугольника лежат в полуплоскости или на границе. Пересечение есть весь многоугольник.
3. Некоторые вершины многоугольника лежат вне полуплоскости, а некоторые — внутри. Это интересный случай, рассмотрим его.

Будем обходить многоугольник от вершины к вершине вдоль его сторон. Понятно,* что у нас вершины, лежащие вне полуплоскости, будут идти подряд, одним куском. Эти все вершины не принадлежат нашему пересечению. Остальные вершины, понятно, как раз принадлежат пересечению.

[image: пример]

Пусть внешние вершины *A*<sub>*k*+1</sub>...*A*<sub>*n*</sub>, тогда прямая, задающая полуплоскость, пересекает отрезки *A*<sub>*k*</sub>*A*<sub>*k*+1</sub> и *A*<sub>*n*</sub>*A*<sub>*n*+1</sub> в точках *P* и *Q*. Тогда наш новый многоугольник получается заменой цепочки *A*<sub>*k*+1</sub>...*A*<sub>*n*</sub> на вершины *P* и *Q*.

Имея итоговый многоугольник, разрезаем его на треугольники диагоналями и заполняем.

---

*пусть доказывают математики, а нам для выпуклого многоугольника самоочевидно

Comment: Вот это как раз тот метод, который в уродских случаях (сильно вытянутый треугольник в частности), будет ломаться из-за проблем с точностью арифметики.

Comment: @gbg: А в этом случае растеризация будет лучше? А что для огромных треугольников? Или наоборот маленьких, сравнимых с шагом растеризации?

Comment: На практике, обычно как раз есть некое разумное требование о точности поиска, из которого и следует выбор шага растеризации.

Растеризация - штука, которая хорошо параллелится. Что приятно.

Можно также предложить алгоритм BSP - деления пространства. Сажаем треугольники в объемлющие прямоугольники. Если пересеклись - делим каждый на 4 равные части, отбрасываем те, что перестали содержать исходные треугольники, для тех, которые еще содержат треугольники - еще одно деление, и так до тех пор, пока нужной точности не достигнем.

Comment: @gbg: А вы можете привести пример, на котором определение пересечения геометрически даст большие отклонения? Потому что я как-то не могу сконструировать такой пример в уме.

Comment: Представьте, что вы ищите пересечение двух весьма длинных отрезков (сторон треугольников), которые почти параллельны. В этом случае вы будете вынуждены решать систему линейных уравнений с плохо обусловленной матрицей; в результате получите, в лучшем случае, точку с координатами (NaN, NaN), в худшем - огромную погрешность.

Часто такая задача ставится для группы фигур (ищем кто и с кем пересекся). В таком случае, из-за погрешностей, получим решение, содержащее внутренние противоречия. При растеризации этого не будет.

Comment: @gbg: Я понимаю, что такое плохо обусловленная система. Но мне кажется, что при поиске пересечения эффекта не будет, т. к. решение будет по идее гарантировать, что область пересечения лежит внутри обеих треугольников. Можете предоставить пример с **конкретными** числами?

Comment: так это нужно написать программу, реализующую вашу идею, а затем под нее подобрать пример, который ее свалит.

Comment: @gbg: Без такого примера не кажется ли вам ваше утверждение из первого комментария голосоловным?

Comment: Это выглядит так.Однако, я сам реализовывал похожую идею. Работает, работает, потом выдался частный случай - получите дырку. Это был (и есть) генератор сеток для МКЭ. Стабильнее BSP-образных алгоритмов для вычислительной топологии я ничего предложить не могу.